# Adding large files to IO.Compression.ZipArchiveEntry throws OutOfMemoryException Exception

Tags: c#, out-of-memory, zip

I am trying to add a large video file(~500MB) to an ArchiveEntry by using this code:

```
using (var zipFile = ZipFile.Open(outputZipFile, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
{
    var zipEntry = zipFile.CreateEntry("largeVideoFile.avi");
    using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(zipEntry.Open()))
    {
        using (FileStream fs = File.Open(@"largeVideoFile.avi", FileMode.Open))
        {
            var buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
            using (var data = new BinaryReader(fs))
            {
                int read;
                while ((read = data.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    writer.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the error

> System.OutOfMemoryException

when writer.Write is called, alltought I used a intermediate buffer....

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: You can simplify the code by removing the readers / writers and using stream.copyto. Doubt it fixes the problem.

Comment: Take a look at `AddEntry(name, stream)` (don't close the stream before calling `Save`) and `AddFile(name, nameInFileSystem)`

Comment: @CodesInChaos: you mean to use `zipFile.CreateEntryFromFile` -> still doesn't work. I accepted the answer with changing the CPU arhitecture to X64 but the inefficiency of the ZipArchiveEntry is worth pointing out when `ZipArchiveMode.Update` is specified(this leads to loading the whole content of the zip in memory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build the application as any CPU and execute it in a x64 machine. This should fix the issue. (Or directly build the application as x64).

Videos normally cannot be compressed a lot and the zip file probably remains in memory until the are completely created.

Comment: Is there a go to page about compression similar to the one(s) about floating point?  The belief that just zipping anything makes it smaller, even if you're zipping something that's already compressed, seems to be becoming more popular!

Comment: I am accepting this as an answer, seems to work now. Although I will point out the inefficiency of the IO.Compression.ArchiveEntry class which needs to load all the ZipArchive contents in Memory when the "ZipArchiveMode.Update" is specified. (horrible)  From msdn : _The content of the entire archive is held in memory, and no data is written to the underlying file or stream until the archive is disposed._ [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchivemode(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: That's probably because the compression is done when all the data is available to increase the compression efficiency.

Comment: Remember to remove the temp buffer thing!