# System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive work with Large File

Tags: c#, ssis, c#-ziparchive

I have [a code](http://pastebin.com/cku9Nw8P) that is SSIS script task to zip file written in C#.

I have problem when zipping 1gb (approxymately) file.

I try to implement [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28360775/adding-large-files-to-io-compression-ziparchiveentry-throws-outofmemoryexception) and still get error 'System.OutOfMemoryException'

> System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
>          at ST_4cb59661fb81431abcf503766697a1db.ScriptMain.AddFileToZipUsingStream(String sZipFile, String sFilePath, String sFileName, String sBackupFolder, String sPrefixFolder) in c:\Users\dtmp857\AppData\Local\Temp\vsta\84bef43d323b439ba25df47c365b5a29\ScriptMain.cs:line 333
>          at ST_4cb59661fb81431abcf503766697a1db.ScriptMain.Main() in c:\Users\dtmp857\AppData\Local\Temp\vsta\84bef43d323b439ba25df47c365b5a29\ScriptMain.cs:line 131

This is the snippet of code when zipping file:

```
protected bool AddFileToZipUsingStream(string sZipFile, string sFilePath, string sFileName, string sBackupFolder, string sPrefixFolder)
{
    bool bIsSuccess = false;

    try
    {
        if (File.Exists(sZipFile))
        {
            using (ZipArchive addFile = ZipFile.Open(sZipFile, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
            {
                addFile.CreateEntryFromFile(sFilePath, sFileName);

                //Move File after zipping it
                BackupFile(sFilePath, sBackupFolder, sPrefixFolder);
            }
       }
       else
       {
       //from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28360775/adding-large-files-to-io-compression-ziparchiveentry-throws-outofmemoryexception
           using (var zipFile = ZipFile.Open(sZipFile, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
           {
               var zipEntry = zipFile.CreateEntry(sFileName);

               using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(zipEntry.Open()))
               using (FileStream fs = File.Open(sFilePath, FileMode.Open))
               {
                   var buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];

                   using (var data = new BinaryReader(fs))
                   {
                        int read;

                        while ((read = data.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                            writer.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                   }
               }
          }

          //Move File after zipping it
          BackupFile(sFilePath, sBackupFolder, sPrefixFolder);
      }

      bIsSuccess = true;
  }

  catch (Exception ex)
  {
     throw ex;
  }

  return bIsSuccess;
}
```

What I am missing, please give me suggestion maybe tutorial or best practice handling this problem.

Comment: Are you running SSIS in [32bit or 64 bit](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2015/02/is-my-ssis-package-running-in-32-or-64.html)?

Comment: 32 bit, Sir.. My OS is 32 bit. So, this is SSIS 32 Bit

Comment: Are you sure your code runs else block anytime?

Comment: Yes. Always run in else since I delete the file before zipping

Comment: 32 bit is very memory limited (and heck, who runs a 32 bit operating system in 2015? Really?). You could consider moving this code out of C# and call a command line zip variant to do the compression.

Comment: This is request from company Sir. No 3rd party, no UnOfficial dll, just use standard library, and no need to install anything. Must be in Script Task SSIS and use Official Dll.

Comment: http://blog.codinghorror.com/dude-wheres-my-4-gigabytes-of-ram/ Let's assume you have at most 3GB of addressable memory space. Some amount of that is going to be needed for Windows to run. Let's call it 3/4 of a GB. Now we're down to 2 1/4 GB of memory. Running the VS SSIS designer? There's another 1/2 GB of ram gone. When SSIS starts, it's going to invoke the dtexec wrapper so we can debug operations, there's another 1/4 of a gig gone. We're at 1.5 GB of available memory at the very outset of processing. You're about to read a 1 gigabyte file into memory and then compress it. That won't work

Comment: Good explanation, Sir.. It is helpful to explain how can this won't work. Upvote for You.

Comment: Have you looked at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28363155/518404

Comment: Thank You @Quintonn. finally I ask to use 3rd party ionic library. Good explanation thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post but what can I say, it helped me sort out some stuff and still comes up as a top hit on Google.

So there is definitely something wrong with the System.IO.Compression library!
First and Foremost...

**You must make sure to turn off 32-Preferred**. Having this set (in my case with a build for "AnyCPU") causes so many inconsistent issues.

Now with that said, I took some demo files (several less than 500MB, one at 500MB, and one at 1GB), and created a sample program with 3 buttons that made use of the 3 methods.

```
Button 1 - ZipArchive.CreateFromDirectory(AbsolutePath, TargetFile);
Button 2 - ZipArchive.CreateEntryFromFile(AbsolutePath, RelativePath);
Button 3 - Using the [16 * 1024] Byte Buffer method from above
```

Now here is where it gets interesting. (Assuming that the program is built as "AnyCPU" and with NO 32 Preferred check)... all 3 Methods worked on a Windows 64-Bit OS, regardless of how much memory it had.

However, as soon as I ran the same test on a 32-Bit OS, regardless of how much memory it had, ONLY method 1 worked!

Method 2 and 3 blew up with the outofmemory error AND to add salt to it, method 3 (the preferred method of chunking) actually corrupted more files than method #2!

By messed up, I mean that of my files, the 500MB and the 1GB file ended up in the zipped archive but at a size less than the original (it was basically truncated).

So I dunno... since there are not many 32-bit OS around anymore, I guess maybe it is a moot point.

But seems like there are some bugs in the System.IO.Compression Framework!